# How do I pass a variable into regex with Node js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, regex, variables

So basically, I have a regular expression which is

```
var regex1 = /10661\" class=\"fauxBlockLink-linkRow u-concealed\">([\s\S]*?)<\/a>/;

var result=text.match(regex1);
user_activity = result[1].replace(/\s/g, "")
console.log(user_activity);
```

What I'm trying to do is this

```
var number = 1234;
var regex1 = /${number}\" class=\"fauxBlockLink-linkRow u-concealed\">([\s\S]*?)<\/a>/;
```

but it is not working, and when I tried with RegExp, I kept getting errors.

Comment: You can programmatically build your regex string using templates or string addition and pass that string to the `new RegExp(...)` constructor.

Comment: how, can you please elaborate. @jfriend00

Comment: Folks who voted to dup this, please find a better dup.  That was a python question, not a Javascript question.  Things are not exactly the same.

Comment: I provided an example in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build the regex string with templates and/or string addition and then pass it to the `RegExp` constructor.  One key in doing that is to get the escaping correct as you need an extra level of escaping for backslashes because the interpretation of the string takes one level of backslash, but you need one to survive as it gets to the RegExp contructor.  Here's a working example:

```js
function match(number, str) {
    let r = new RegExp(`${number}" class="fauxBlockLink-linkRow u-concealed">([\\s\\S]*?)<\\/a>`);
    return str.match(r);
}


const exampleHTML = '<a href="something" class="aaa1234" class="fauxBlockLink-linkRow u-concealed">Some link text</a>';

console.log(match(1234, exampleHTML));
```

Note, using regex to match HTML like this becomes very order-sensitive (whereas the HTML itself isn't order-sensitive).  And, your regex requires exactly one space between classes which HTML doesn't.  If the class names were in a slightly different order or spacing different in the `<a>` tag, then it would not match.  Depending upon what you're really trying to do, there may be better ways to parse and use the HTML that isn't order-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RegExp` to create regexp from a string and use variables in that string.

```js
var number = 1234;
var regex1 = new RegExp(`${number}aa`);

console.log("1234aa".match(regex1));
```

Comment: I tried already, this is what my code looks like
```
var text = fs.readFileSync('data.txt','utf8')
var number = 1234;
var regex1 = new RegExp(``<a href=\"\/forum\/search\/member\?user_id=${number}\" class=\"fauxBlockLink-linkRow u-concealed\">([\s\S]*?)<\/a>``);
var result=text.match(regex1);
console.log(result);
```
I get 'null' as output

Comment: I tried your regex, It looks like the problem was the escapes and _([\s\S]*?)_ part. It requires double escapes. I put a sample on the link  https://jsfiddle.net/fhb9jv0k/2/

Comment: I'm not sure. I tried your code, its not grouping what is supposed to be between the
''([\s\S]*?)'', its just typing it in full, when I tried to use [] it did not match

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nucremp9/1/ this is what I mean

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6ocga3f7/
what I'm trying to extract is '1,193'
when I insert the full actual html code on my PC, it doesn't work, on the website it does

Comment: All good, I figured it out thanks a lot, you code helped,
the issue was in the way i was reading the file, so the content the script was being performed on was wrong all the time

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the method of Adem,

```
function escapeRegExp(string) {
    return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'); // $& means the whole matched string
}


var number = 1234; 

var firstPart = `<a href="/forum/search/member?user_id=${number}" class="fauxBlockLink-linkRow u-concealed">`

var regexpString = escapeRegExp(firstPart) + '([\\s\\S]*?)' + escapeRegExp('</a>');

console.log(regexpString)


var sample = `<a href="/forum/search/member?user_id=1234" class="fauxBlockLink-linkRow u-concealed"> </a>`

var regex1 = new RegExp(regexpString); 

console.log(sample.match(regex1));
```

in the first place the issue was actually the way I was reading the file, the data I was applying the match on, was undefined.